# How to clear the value of an Autocomplete Box?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

Just like many things in WPF, sometimes the easiest things are the ones that are hardest to find examples for! How do you clear out the current text of an AutoCompleteBox? In my OnFocus event I want to make sure that the user is given a clear box for entry. So my event procedure looks like

```
private void autGlobal_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteBox acb = (AutoCompleteBox)sender;
    if (acb.SearchText == "Search Term")
    {
        //clear out the box if it has the focus                    
        this.autGlobal.Text = "";
    }         
}
```

However, setting the text property directly does not seem to work. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This works fine for me. Instead `this.autGlobal.Text = "";` use `acb.Text = "";` seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer after spending a ton of time on this and the XAML. This code example will not work when the IsTextCompletionEnabled option is set to true in the XAML. I set it to false and this code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need reset Selected Item too.

```
private void SearchAutoCompleteBox_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SearchAutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem = null;

    SearchAutoCompleteBox.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: setting SelectedItem = null; did the trick , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the property on your local variable?

```
acb.Text = string.Empty;
```

I have a feeling there may be additional code affecting the .Text field when the focus or textchange events are firing.

Comment: I think you may be right about other events firing. I've noticed that the property will set fine but then something else takes over and makes the content of the search box become highlighted and stay as is. Is there a way for me to check that or override them?

Comment: You could subclass the AutoCompleteBox and override its methods. There may be unforeseen problems doing this though. Those _secret_ events might actually be doing something it needs to perform auto-completion correctly. The AutoCompleteBox source is [available](http://wpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) if you want to examine the code to see what's going on.